# PHPMailer plain text email adds new line at the end

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, plaintext

I'm trying to get rid of new line at the end of plain text email message I'm sending with PHPMailer.

What I'm doing exactly is:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->isHTML(false);  
$mail->Body = $xxx1."\r\n".$xxx2."\r\n".$xxx3;
$mail->setFrom("no-reply@xxx.xx", "xxx");
$mail->addReplyTo("no-reply@xxx.xx", "xxx");
$mail->addAddress($to, $name);
$mail->Subject = $topic;
$mail->send();
```

Everything is  fine except for the new line that is being added after the message body, it's something like:

[msg screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PHM4.jpg)

Maybe someone has any idea how to remove that newline marker from the end of message?

Thanks!

EDIT: 
$xxx3 variable is a param passed to mail sending function. It is set to either "no" or "yes".

Comment: where does your `$xxx3` variable come from?

Comment: It's a param passed to mail sending function. It is set to either "no" or "yes" in easy if/else statement (it's a form disclaimer checkbox representation)

Comment: You can use: `trim($xxx1."\r\n".$xxx2."\r\n".$xxx3, " \r\n")` as `Body`

Answer (score 1):

PHPMailer does add line breaks while it's assembling the MIME structure for a message. See the [`createBody`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/177839e22fd1646cb1186f0608f3f5e74997072c/class.phpmailer.php#L2086) method. I think there is an RFC requirement that message bodies must end with a line break (can't remember exactly which one right now), so one is always added to make sure. If it's that critical I'd recommend you strip your trailing line break first:

```
$mail->Body = rtrim($xxx1."\r\n".$xxx2."\r\n".$xxx3, "\r\n");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I tried to do as You said however outcome is the same. Do You think I should consider editing phpMailer files?

Comment: You can do it without editing PHPMailer files - just create a subclass, copy the createBody method into it and edit as you like. If the `rtrim` didn't do anything it suggests `Body` didn't have a trailing break to start with and PHPMailer may be adding two.